# Pods Framework URL displaying an extra http

Tags: php, wordpress, pods-framework

I'm having trouble displaying the URL, it comes with an extra HTTP:/ before the image URL [url showing http:/http://site-url.com/wp-content/uploads/year/month/img.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L31Gc.png)

My code :

```
$args = array("post_type" => "partner");

$partner= new WP_Query( $args );

if($partner->have_posts()):
    while($partner->have_posts()):
        $partner->the_post();
        $logo = get_field("logo-partner.guid");
?>
<img src="<?= $logo ?>" >
```

Comment: Are you using ACF too? If not, is this the exact code you are using?

Comment: Nops, I disabled the plugin also the variables names are different...just in case

Comment: Do you have the definition for the get_field function, is that one you made yourself? That's an ACF function

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the HTML render itself is outputting it's own `<img>`, so try just `echo $logo` perhaps?